# Make a preventBack function not work on a certain url

Tags: javascript, html, back-button

I'm making a webpage and I'm really new to this. I have a `preventBack` function that works great, but I want a certain page (specifically the name is `restart.html`) not to be affected by this script.
I have been searching for some time and tried different solutions and but nothing worked.

This is the function:

```
function preventBack() {
  window.history.forward();
}
setTimeout("preventBack()", 0);
window.onunload = function () { 
  null;
};
```

This function is written on `page1.html` (for example), and it affects `page2.html` (because of the `window.history.forward`, if I'm not mistaken).
I just want it to change its behavior so that if you've clicked the restart button by mistake, you can just go back to the previous page and continue.
I've tried it with if and else, and also changing the number for the timeout, but it doesn't work as I want it to.

Comment: If is your first website I'd highly suggest you learn proper HTML syntax and structure before attempting to implement the most hated feature imaginable

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! But this webpage is also part of an assignment that I have a deadline for and I can't learn the proper way of doing it in such a short time, I just needed a quick solution to implement this feature. Do you know how to do it?